# How to plot overlapping squares with similar size?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to plot a pattern with overlapping squares using matplotlib.pyplot. I am not sure how to get all squares of the same size.

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([2.2,2.2,3.5,3.5,2.2],[4.1,2.5,2.5,4.1,4.1],linestyle='solid',color="red")
plt.plot([3.2,4.2,4.2,3.2,3.2],[3.2,3.2,4.5,4.5,3.2],linestyle='solid',color="blue")
plt.plot([2.5,2.5,3.8,3.8,2.5],[1.8,3.8,3.8,1.8,1.8],linestyle='solid',color="green")
plt.plot([3.6,4.8,4.8,4.8,3.6,3.6],[2.2,2.2,0,0,0,2.2],linestyle='solid',color="black")
plt.title('square pattern')
```

Comment: A comment: to show squares as squares `plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')` helps to have x-distances equal to y-distances.

Comment: Please describe your goal more clearly. You now have 4 rectangles of different sizes. Do you want squares with the same surface area? Squares with the same centre as the rectangles? .... ?

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I want to  have all 4 rectangles to be  squares of the same size

Comment: You don't tell what size, nor where they should be located.

Comment: Thanks.Squares can be any size but equal. 3 squares diagonally overlapping one another. 4th square at right top overlapping the top two diagonal squares.  This is just for learning purpose.  With my code I got the pattern but I want all the rectangles look like squares of the same size.  sorry I am not able to post a picture here.  Thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code to draw 4 squares of the same size. The squares are represented by their lower left position. You can change these coordinates to easily position each square.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import sqrt

colors = [ 'crimson', 'dodgerblue', 'limegreen', 'black']

side = 2
square1 = [1, 1.3]
square2 = [2.1, 0.5]
square3 = [1.3, 1.6]
square4 = [1.7, 2.8]
squares = [square1, square2, square3, square4]

for square, col in zip(squares, colors):
    x = square[0]
    y = square[1]
    plt.plot([x, x + side, x + side, x, x],
             [y, y, y + side, y + side, y],
             color=col, linestyle='solid')
plt.title('square pattern')
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: This is cool.  Thanks so much for your your time and showing how to write the code to get this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to get squares of all the same size, with the sum of the area of the rectangles equal to the sum of the areas of the squares. And with each square having the same center as the rectangle.

The area of each rectangle is width x height. Dividing the sum of the areas by the number of rectangles finds the average area. The side of a square with this area is its square root.

Code to calculate and draw the squares. The original rectangles are drawn lighter for comparison.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import sqrt

colors = [ 'crimson', 'dodgerblue', 'limegreen', 'black']

rect1 = [[2.2,2.2,3.5,3.5,2.2],[4.1,2.5,2.5,4.1,4.1]]
rect2 = [[3.2,4.2,4.2,3.2,3.2],[3.2,3.2,4.5,4.5,3.2]]
rect3 = [[2.5,2.5,3.8,3.8,2.5],[1.8,3.8,3.8,1.8,1.8]]
rect4 = [[3.6,4.8,4.8,4.8,3.6,3.6],[2.2,2.2,0,0,0,2.2]]
rects = [rect1, rect2, rect3, rect4]

total_area = 0
for rect in rects:
    width = max(rect[0]) - min(rect[0])
    height = max(rect[1]) - min(rect[1])
    total_area += width * height
square_side = sqrt(total_area / len(rects))
half = square_side / 2

for rect, col in zip(rects, colors):
    center_x = (max(rect[0]) + min(rect[0])) / 2
    center_y = (max(rect[1]) + min(rect[1])) / 2
    plt.plot(rect[0], rect[1], color=col, linestyle='solid', alpha=0.2)
    plt.plot([center_x - half, center_x - half, center_x + half, center_x + half, center_x - half],
             [center_y + half, center_y - half, center_y - half, center_y + half, center_y + half],
             color=col, linestyle='solid')
plt.title('square pattern')
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Many Thanks. for showing the code.   The code looks elegant and  I  changed the code for the 4th rectangle just to get the overlap